# "Slicing" a recurring task in a Gantt view?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar, gantt-view

Let's say I have recurring task in a Gantt view that happens every Monday. Let's call it a "preview". If I open this task in a Gantt view instead of calendar view it shows one huge bar all the way to end. Is there a way to "slice" it to a small bars that are only size of a Monday?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we cannot slice a recurring task in a Gantt view, it is by design.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I thought so but it's always worth to ask if somebody has figured something out.